# How to stabilize the perspective view obtained by homography through a video?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, homography

I have a video on which I detect keypoints using a neural network. During the video, a PTZ camera is moving.
Each frame (1280x720) in input is resized (512x512) to have a better performance in terms of inference time. Once these keypoints are detected on the frame, I find the homography between the frame and a template thanks to the `cv2.findHomography` function. Then I use the `cv2.warpPerspective` function to get my image in 'bird eye view'. Finally, I upscale the result with the original dimensions.

My problem is that when I put together the result of each frame to create a 'bird eye view' video, there are some kind of 'jumps/shaking'. The results of each frame are very close but there is still a shift from one frame to another.

My opinion is that at each frame the `cv2.findHomography` function gives us approximate results and that for a given frame there are several solutions whose reprojection is visually and mathematically acceptable. But put together, these approximations create these 'shaking' because we lose the dependency between 2 consecutive frames (due to a more or less smooth movement of the camera) for which the results must, in my opinion, be close.

Do you have any idea how to limit these 'shaking'?

I don't know if my explanation is clear, feel free to tell me if it is not.

Have a good day.

Comment: One issue might be that you have fluctuations from varying terrain relief effects where the local terrain varies from one frame to another. Therefore not all pixels are at the same ground elevation. The other point is that using control point matching and then finding the homography is a best fit process that leads to slight fluctuation in the camera model (XYZ pitch, roll, yaw) due to different control points being used. Sorry, I do not know how to stabilize these effects. You could try aligning the first frame to the template. Then the second frame to the corrected first frame and so on.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
Indeed, the variation of elevation could explain these fluctuations but I forgot to specify it, all the control points remain at z=0 (z being the normal axis to the ground).
I have also tried "aligning the first frame to the template. Then the second frame to the corrected first frame and so on" as you said, by calculating the homography between 2 consecutive frames but also by calculating the camera displacement from one frame to another. And none of these methods allowed me to remove these fluctuations...

Comment: Even if your control points are at Z=0, you can get variations due to elevation differences across the image. When the elevation differences are viewed at different locations and orientations, you get terrain relief distortions in your corrected image, as "ground" points appear to be at different distances. This causes local shifts. If your "ground" plane is relatively flat, then this effect will be minimum. But if it is not and your camera height is low, then these effects get amplified.

Comment: Okay, thanks, I see what you mean. 
In my case, my ground plane is totally flat and the camera height is relatively high compared to the ground plane.

Comment: The likely just fluctuations in the control points being used if chosen automatically.

Comment: yes certainly. But how to get a smooth rendering ? Using a Kalman filter ?